# How can I create an Org link for each email sent by mu4e?

Tags: org-mode, mu4e

I'm using org-mode and mu4e. I'd like to have each email become the active link so that I can link to it in Org. When viewing an email, I can `C-c C-l` (bound to `(org-store-link)`) to make a link to it, and then elsewhere in Org `C-c l` to paste the link. I'd like the `(org-store-link)` part to happen automagically each time I send an email.

I've found two hooks: `message-send-hook` and `message-sent-hook` but am not sure where to call `(org-store-link)`. I've tried that in a function on each hook, but it doesn't work. I think there is additional trickery to catch the just-sent (or sending) message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Danie Roux](https://github.com/danieroux) developed a solution. See:

https://github.com/danieroux/emacs/blob/master/mine/djr-org-mu4e-capture-sent.el

His instructions are:

- Define `djr/mu4e-org-mode-capture-template-for-sent-email`
- Then, either:

  - Call `djr/mu4e-compose-new-with-follow-up`
  - Or set `djr/org-mu4e-must-capture-message`

After sending an email, `org-capture` will be called with that template. `%a` will be the link to that email.

`org-insert-link` will have the email in the list of links, regardless of whether you set the flag or not.

Answer (score 3):

My first suggestion would be to try the following.

```
(add-hook 'message-send-hook (lambda () (org-store-link nil)))
```

Since you said you tried the hook, another way is to just combine
`org-store-link` and message sending into a single function.

```
(defun store-link-then-send-message ()
  "Call `org-store-link', then send current email message."
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively #'org-store-link)
  (call-interactively #'message-send-and-exit))

(define-key mu4e-compose-mode-map "\C-c\C-c" #'store-link-then-send-message)
```

This assumes you're using `message-send-and-exit` to send the message. You could do something identical with the `message-send` command.

```
(define-key mu4e-compose-mode-map "\C-c\C-c" #'store-link-then-send-message)
```

Comment: The latter works, sort-of. It stores a link to the file, not a link to the message (message ID). I found code that seems to implement what I want, but it appears surprisingly overly-complex for this simple task (although, granted, not simple enough that I have been able to figure it out myself). That code is here: https://github.com/danieroux/emacs/blob/master/mine/djr-mu4e.el

Comment: @mankoff When you call `org-store-link` manually, does it link to the file or the message? If it links to the messaage, when are you calling it (before or after sending)?

Comment: http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Creating-org_002dmode-links.html When viewing messages, `org-store-link` stores a link to the message. When viewing headers, to the search that created that header view. When editing a draft, it stores it to the file. Probably because "msgid" or other such fields aren't yet set? After sending, it stores a link to the header/message visible, not the just-sent message.

Comment: @mankoff I see. I was misled because on the regular message-mode a Message-ID field is created for you when you call org-store-link, even if the message isn't sent. I'll try to figure how mu4e does it.